# Symfony2: How to set default value for a field DateTime

Tags: php, forms, symfony, datetime

I work with Symfony 2.8

I have a table named: "Docentes" with a DateTime field "fechaAlta"

**I need the default value of this field is "today" when I add a new record**

I generate CRUD, using command  `generate:doctrine:crud`

In the file "DocentesController.php" Symfony create two function: "newAction" and "editAction" (among other). Both using the **same Form**, insert in the file "DocentesType.php" in the folder "Form":

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ->add('fechaAlta', 'date')
        ->add('dni')
        #
    ;
}
```

I tried two solutions:

ONE: In the Entity file named, "Docentes.php" I add the function:

```
  public function  __construct()
{
$this->fechaAlta = new \DateTime();    
}
```

But when I use the form to add the new record, the field "fechaAlta" is displayed with the values​​: Day 01, Month 01 and Year 2011. Not with the current date.

TWO:

I edit the function buildForm:

```
->add('fechaAlta', 'date', array(
                'data' => new \DateTime()))
 ##
```

Now, when I add a new record, I obtain again the values: Day 01, Month 01 and Year 2011 but when I edit a record, Symfony change my original value, for example 2016-03-25 and set the today value! All the opposite of what I need!

Comment: When I change: '->add('fechaAlta', 'date', array(
                'data' => new \DateTime()))' to '->add('fechaAlta', 'date', array(
    'data' => new \DateTime('now')))' I obtain the date today in case a new record, but remains the problem when I edit a record.

Comment: Are you 100% certain your date/time/timezone settings on your server & php.ini are correct? Anyway, you could call `$entity->setFetchAlta(new \DateTime());` in the `newAction` I'd guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace :

```
public function  __construct()
{
$this->fechaAlta = new \DateTime();    
}
```

by

```
public function  __construct()
{
$this->fechaAlta = new \DateTime('now');    
}
```

Comment: The argument is surely optional, see [Example #2, 3rd part](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) in the php docs.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('fechaAlta', 'date', array(
            'empty_data' => new \DateTime('now'),
        ))
        ->add('dni')
    ;
}
```